# How to have a HDD usable by both Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive, windows

I haven't found a similar question. I have an SSD which runs windows and Ubuntu. Additionally, I installed a 1 TB HHD to the SATA 2 connector. I wish to be able to write and read files from both OS. So far I can only read and write from Windows and only read from Ubuntu. How can I make it fully work with Ubuntu? I tried resetting the HDD from Ubuntu and that made it the other way around where Windows was not able to write to the HDD.
I tried using nautilus to change the permissions directly but it does not allow me to change them.
The /etc/fstab has the following for my drive

```
/dev/sdb1    /media/mynewdrive   vfat    defaults     0        2
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the contents of the `/etc/fstab` file? This will show how the 1TB HDD is being mounted. Generally Ubuntu can read and write to NTFS via the `ntfs-3g` driver, but this depends on both permissions and mount rules.

Comment: Most often this fast startup is on: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation And best to add mount with good parameters to fstab. Note that Disks can create entry, but does not use good parameters. You need to change those, so often best to create own entry. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions Good example for parameters: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2420861&p=13865822#post13865822

Comment: I have my disk in FAT32 and when I start Ubuntu the disk is mounted already. My only issue is unable to write to it

Comment: I updated the question @Matigo